# Как внедрить функцию шпион с 3-мя методами?

Tags: javascript

```
function spyOn (func) {

  this.func = func; 
  this.func.counter = 0;
  this.func.counter++;

  this.func.callCount = function () {
        return this.counter;
    }
  this.func.returned = function () {

        return 'returned';
    } 
  this.func.wasCalledWith = function () {

        return 'calledWith';
    }    

  return this.func;
}



function returns1 () { return 1; }

var spy = spyOn(returns1);

console.log(spy.callCount());//0
console.log(spy.returned(1));//false
console.log(spy.wasCalledWith('hello'));//false

spy('hello', 'hi', 'howdy');
spy('goodbye', 'bye', 'see ya');

console.log(spy.callCount()); //2
console.log(spy.returned(1));//true
console.log(spy.wasCalledWith('hi'));//true
console.log(spy.wasCalledWith('bye'));//true
```

Должно работать 3 метода.

1. callCount возвращает кол-во раз которое была вызвана spyOn, у меня counter каждый раз обнуляется.
2. returned(x) возвращает true если spyOn хоть раз вернул x.
3. wasCalledWith(x) возвращает true если spyOn хоть раз был вызван с аргументом x.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function spyOn(func) {
  let calls = 0
  let all = []
  let val

  const spy = function(...args) {
    calls++
    all.push(...args)
    val = func.apply(this, args)
    return val
  }

  spy.callCount = () => calls
  spy.wasCalledWith = (x) => all.some((a) => x === a)
  spy.returned = (x) => x === val

  return spy
}
```

Comment: второй пункт не выполнен